# Webpacked and transpiled JSX exports can't be re-imported elsewhere

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

I'm trying to make a library which contains JSX, and uses webpack with babel-loader to transpile it to a CommonJS module that can be re-imported and used in other places.

An example of one of the JSX files looks like this

```
export const Item1 = (props) => (
  <div id={props.id}>   
  </div>
);
```

And there's a main entry point index.js that just does this:

```js
import Item1 from '../jsx/item1'
import Item2 from '../jsx/item2'
...etc

export { Item1, Item2 }
```

Then my webpack.config.js has this

```js
configs.push({
    entry: "./jsx/index.js",
    output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
      filename: "jsx.js"
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: [".js", ".jsx"]
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          use: 'babel-loader',
          test: /\.(js|jsx)?$/,
        },
      ]
    }
   }
```

which when run produces a file in dist called `jsx.js`, which looks right as best I can tell, it has all my transpiled  JSX inside as expected. I'm using the @babel/react preset with automatic runtime. I've then set up my `main` in `package.json` to point to this jsx.js file.

When I then install the library in another place, and try and use it, the imported items are just empty objects.

```
import { Item1, Item2 } from 'jsx-library'
console.log(Item1) // prints undefined
<Item1 />
```

That last line gets the error `Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.`

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: You didn't configured the bundle to be a lib, in this case it's treated as an app. Also it's possible that named exports can become default depending on module config, this is what the error says

Comment: Thanks that was it yeah - it needed a `libraryTarget` in the output.